# apt upgrade fail with 401 on https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu

Tags: apt, esm

I am trying to do a

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

However there are a lot of messages saying that I am not authorized against https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu

```
Err:3 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 imagemagick-6-common all 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.15+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 185.125.190.23 443]
```

After some searching I understand that ESM is for Ubuntu customer that pay a subscription. I have used this Ubuntu instance for quite long time and is not aware of ESM nor opted in to it.

The instance is a LightSail from AWS. Did I understand anything wrong? What can I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your settings in the software updater.  Especially the last tab.  You are correct that the update is being denied because you are not authorized to connect to that server.  It's easy and free to create an account to do livepatch updates.

[image]